# Select a field value before deleting a row

Tags: php, mysql

The following are my table fields:

```
pk_stu_sub_id | fk_stu_class_id | fk_class_sub_id | fk_user_id | timestamp
```

What I need to do is delete the row when `pk_stu_sub_id = (variable)` but get the value of `fk_stu_class_id` before deleting it. I need to write PHP code for this.

Is it possible to do this?
If so, then how?

Comment: Two SQL queries. 1st select the value, 2nd delete entire row.

Comment: What do you want to do with the value of fk_stu_class_id?

Comment: I've to update other table using this value

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger on your table that when delete each row, trigger will fire and 
save fk_stu_class_id in another table 
For more about triggers see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

First query for the id of the row to be deleted:

```
SELECT fk_stu_class_id 
FROM table
WHERE pk_stu_sub_id = variable
```

Then delete the row

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE pk_stu_sub_id = variable
```